# how to display state inside input tag

Tags: reactjs

I'm building the following react component and trying to add hidden to my input box.

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state={display:'hidden'};
}


render() {

return(
       <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" this.state.display />           
       </div>
);
}
}
```

I also tried {this.state.display} but I get unexpected token

Comment: that doesn't make any sense.  could you explain more fully?

Comment: " trying to add hidden to my input box." ?!?!?   What's this question my friend .. Sorry but no meaning .

Comment: The true way to make a hidden input is by [setting `type=hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden). All other answers here are just CSS rules that hide the element, not turn it into a hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need `hidden` as a prop on the tag, to show in your code like `<input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" hidden />`, which I believe that's what you're asking...you have to make a slight change to your code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    display: {
      hidden: undefined
    }
  };
}


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" {...this.state.display} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In order to hide, you set the state of `hidden` under `display` to anything not `null` or `undefined`.

So: `this.setState({display: { hidden: <STATECHANGE>}})`

Answer (score -1):

**Using input `type` attribute:**

```
<input type="text" type={this.state.display} />
```

**Using `style`:**

```
<input type="text" style={{...this.state}} />
```

And change `display: hidden` to `display: none` inside your state object.

Answer (score -1):

Either , replace `display` by `visibility` , or replace `hidden` by `none`.

Either you have `{display: 'none'}` or `{visibility: 'hidden'}` .

Then answer of @Linas will be valid . I mean :

```
<input type="text" style={this.state} />
```

or

```
<input type="text" style={{...this.state}} />
```

Both render the same.